# Match all the numbers whose digits follow a strict ascending order - Regular expression

Tags: python, python-re

Given a one line of input string, for example: "7989 123 778 45 6"
I want output to be "123" "45" "6", since the output numbers should be strictly ascending.

Have to use Regular Expression with group.

Comment: `r'0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?'`  Hmm.  That will also match the empty string.

Comment: What should be the output for `"123 6 45"` and for `"456 678"` ?

Comment: @Lenormju For "123 6 45", the output should be "123" "6" "45". For "456 678", the output should be "456" "678".

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you. I've tried that but I do not want the '' output.

Answer (score 0):

It was ambiguous in your question whether it should be the digits in a number that should follow a strict ascending order or the numbers themselves.
Here is a solution :

```py
import re
from typing import Tuple


def find(sentence: str) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    pat = re.compile(r"(?:(?<=\D)|^)(0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?)(?=\D|$)")
    return tuple(match.group().strip() for match in pat.finditer(sentence) if match.group())


def check(sentence, expected):  # quick and dirty unit testing
    actual = find(sentence)
    assert actual == expected, (expected, "!=", actual)


check("6", ("6",))
check("7989", ())
check("7989 123", ("123",))
check("7989 123 778", ("123",))
check("7989 123 778 45", ("123", "45",))
check("7989 123 778 45 6 ", ("123", "45", "6",))
check("123 6 45", ("123", "6", "45",))
check("456 678", ("456", "678",))
```

Comment: I learnt that you can't use `^` and `$` in a set (cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552440/11384184)). Also, due to [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) returning non-overlapping matches, the spaces that separate the numbers should not be consumed. Hence I used a **positive lookbehind** ([`(<=`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-22)) and a **lookahead assertion** ([`(?=`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-20)).